# How to check whether a cookie has been set on previous visit?

Tags: java, web-applications, cookies

In a java web application,I want to check whether a user who signs in is a returning user.  How can I check if there is already a cookie that has been set on earlier login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set cookie when user performs log-in:

```
Cookie c = new Cookie("visit", "old")
c.setMaxAge(3600*24*365*1000); // 1 year (for example)
response.addCookie(new Cookie("visit", "old"));
```

Now you can check this cookie when user with new session comes to the system: `request.getCookies()`, then iterates over returned array and find "your" cookie. If cookie exists this is "old" user otherwise the new one.

Answer (score 1):

On `HttpServletRequest` you have a `getCookies()` method that will give you an array of the cookies the client is sending with his request.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies%28%29